# Worker Role vs Web Role with async controllers

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4

Several components of our system have "long running" operations. They can take anywhere from seconds to minutes, and vary in their CPU usage. E.g., report generation will peg a CPU for a few seconds, but data collection is largely spent waiting on a database query.

I am faced with two choices:

(1) Web role + worker role + queue + table. Worker role spins on a queue, gets a message with parameters, does work, updates table with progress and completion flags. Client spins, displaying progress until its marked done. One web role, scale up number of worker roles as needed.

(2) Web role + async method. Make my long running operations use .NET 4.5's async/await stuff, and have the controller actions marked async. Scale up number of web roles as needed.

Option 1 obviously is much more complicated, but has the advantage of keeping the web roles free to do web stuff, and allowing proper queuing if things start getting really busy. Option 2 is simpler and will require less roles and storage resources, but doesn't it have the potential to choke up the entire website if things start getting busy? I am strongly leaning to option 2 just for simplicity. Is there any particular reason not to do this? If the website start slowing down, simply increasing the number of web role instances will solve performance problems right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with most architectural decisions, the answer is only "it depends".

In this case, option (2) is easier to code. If your're not expecting to scale massively, then I would say that's fine.

The key advantage to option (1) is that you have two knobs for scaling: your web roles handle web requests and your worker roles handle the work, and you can scale up your workers independently of your webs.

But unless you're going to scale massively, I wouldn't worry about it. Option (2) can scale quite well, just not with perfect efficiency. And if you do start scaling massively, you can (inefficiently) crank up scaling with option (2) and (presumably) use your massively scaling income to develop option (1).

P.S. You should use `async` for both options.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen posted, this is going to be an "It Depends" type of answer.

In this case I would probably go with either the first option, or an option in between where yuo have the web role, queue, and table, but create an executable that also runs on your web role as a startup executable.

With option 2, your going to be open to connection timeouts, instance restarts, etc and and additional demand for resources will have to be met with scaling your web roles or a code rewrite.

With option 1 (as Stephen pointed out), your workload is separated and you can scale the roles independently. In addition, letting the queues and workers handle the work allows the workers to manage their own lifespan and you can build in some resiliency for planned or unplanned restarts by not removing the queue items until you have finished the job (that way they will resurface if you crash in the middle). You also have the ability to take fuller advantage of the role resources (scale on threads first, then additional instances), as your polling mechanism will be controlling the workload rather than random people hitting the website. On the web side, you can then chose to either have the async method that waits for completion and returns, or you could return a token and let the client poll for completion of the work, either case should be relatively simple code.

Option 1.5 may be the best starting point, though. If your trying to start small, then using a background executable on your web roles will be the cheapest solution. You're going to want to have at least 2 web roles to ensure coverage by the SLA, so this solution would let you start with just those two instances and no more. Build the executable that does the queue polling and report (or whatever) execution seperately, then configure it as a start up task for the web role. This will let you keep the cost down while your starting and the code for those exe's is speerate and becomes the code for your worker role later if you need to expand. The biggest thing to watch for in this situation is that your executable handles all exceptions because if this process exits due to an unhandled exception, it won't get restarted (unlike worker roles, which Azure will continue to just keep on starting every time they die).